# About the return values of the telnet server on windows xp

Tags: network-programming, windows-xp, network-protocols

I am writing a telnet proxy on xp. Now I can telnet to system's telnet server and print its return values sending back to my procedure.

I find a very puzzling phenomenon. When I first telnet to the server,it will ask me to log in. I type in `"tamlok"`, and I can see that it sending back to me that `"116,97,109,108,111,107,10,13"` which is the ascii value of `"tamlok"(10 and 13 means '\n' and '\r')`.

However after I log in,I type in `"tamlok"` again. It sends back to me that `"27,91,56,59,51,52,72,116,0,97,0,108,0,111,0,107,0,27,91,57,59,49,72"`.

I suggest that it returns the unicode so that `"116"` turns into `"116,0"` and so on. But I can't understand the sequence  `"27,91,56,59,51,52,72"` and `"27,91,57,59,49,72"`. I think it maybe a sequence for a special function, just like `{0x1B, 0x5B, 0x48, 0x1B, 0x5B, 0x4A}` will clear the console.

So,how to interpret this?
Any help is welcome!

Comment: Its definitly look like terminal control codes. I suggest you look up VT100 control codes, for example like the ones found [here](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joachim Pileborg.Now it is clear that it is terminal control codes. [An example](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).
So "27,91,56,59,51,52,72" is "[Esc][8;34H" which suits the pattern:
Cursor Home         [{ROW};{COLUMN}H
Sets the cursor position where subsequent text will begin. If no row/column parameters are provided (ie. [H), the cursor will move to the home position, at the upper left of the screen.
So does 27,91,57,59,49,72".